# Identifying cells which contain "/" twice - R

Tags: r, dplyr

My data looks something like this:

```
ID URL
1  example.org/start
2  example.org/search/keyword
3  example.org/searchfindings/366/
4  example.org/searchfindings/
```

Using `dplyr`, I want to subset the columns with IDs 1 and 4, which contain the character `/` exactly twice.

How do I do that?

Comment: It should be a dupe, you can check `subset(df1, str_count(URL, "[/]") ==2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `stringr` package which is part of the `tidyverse`.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- read.table(text = "ID 
1  example.org/start
2  example.org/search/keyword
3  example.org/searchfindings/366/
4  example.org/searchfindings/", header = T)

rows <- str_count(df$URL, pattern = "/")
df[rows == 2, ]

#  ID                         URL
#2  2  example.org/search/keyword
#4  4 example.org/searchfindings/
```